# Cmake seems to be pointing at an old directory for MinGW

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, qt-creator

Running QT Creator on Windows.  I had a package that was giving me warnings about a bug in g++ 4.7, so I downloaded the mingw g++ version 4.6.2.  Problem is that when I run cmake through QT creator, it seems to still be pointing at the old directory (that I've now deleted).  Here's the console output when I run cmake:

```
CMake Error: your RC compiler: "C:/MinGW-4.7.1/bin/windres.exe" was not found.   Please     set CMAKE_RC_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your C compiler: "C:/MinGW-4.7.1/bin/gcc.exe" was not found.   Please set     CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "C:/MinGW-4.7.1/bin/g++.exe" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
```

I'm not sure if the problem is in QT Creator or Cmake or what.  I'm running this stuff on Windows.

Comment: Did you delete CMake's output directory of your project and run configuration stage again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to delete the output directory which CMake creates when the project is configured. This directory contains a lot of cached configuration information, including the paths to toolchain (compiler, linker, etc.). Just delete it and reconfigure the project, and CMake will find the newly installed distribution of MinGW toolchain.

Comment: (Sorry, I'm the original poster, on a different computer atm) Is that different than running a "clean" command from the toolbar? I'm a little new to cmake and qt creator. I did try that though.

Comment: @Patrick | user1306592. Yes it is different. Make clean will clean the build-setup constructed by CMake, but leave the build-setup itself. Deleting CMakeCache.txt will force CMake to re-generate the entire build-setup. Including paths to tools, libraries, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help you guys.  Sorry if my usage of the site is a little clunky, I'm new here.  Got everything sorted out.  You rock!